# Meta Destination Owner Differs From Actual Owner

Tags: sql-server, replication

How can the replication meta data table differ from the properties of the publication through the interface; for instance ...

```
SELECT destination_owner
FROM distribution..MSarticles
```

Yet, when selecting the article properties from the interface of the properties for the publication, it has a different schema.  So in case one, the destination_owner is `One` while in actual properties the owner is `Two`.

What I see is if the destination_owner from MSarticles is NULL, it means that the owner is the same as the source_owner.  Yet, I'm seeing a situation where the two are reporting different destination owners.